# Need to create a lot of views for reporting purposes how to best organise them into folders

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Using Oracle SQL developer,I need to create a lot of sql views, which will probably bloat the view folder and its one that the whole I.T department uses. Is there a way to organise the views into subfolders, If I have a sales report 2018 can put all my views into a subfolder called sales report 2018, if I have a report called sales cancelled I can put all my sql views into a subfolder called sales cancelled

Comment: what you call a folder, the database calls a schema - create as necessary. also, database users are used to having thousands of views at the level, see the database data dictionary as an extreme example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new user.
2. Grant that user the permissions to `SELECT` from the tables you want to use.
3. Create the views so they are owned by that user.

Then when you want to use the views you can either:

1. connect as that user; or
2. grant permission for your usual account to select from that new user's views.

If you go for the second option then, in SQL Developer, after granting permissions you can find the user in the "Other Users" branch at the bottom of the "folder" structure.